# Ошибка ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::operator[]: "index out of range" при записи большого объема данных в excel

Tags: c++, qt, excel

С помощью библиотеки QtXlsx взятой отсюда https://github.com/VSRonin/QtXlsxWriter
пытаюсь записать файл отчёта в формате *.xlsx

```
 void EditorWindow::writeTextRecord()
{
    QString fn = reportData.name + "_record" + ".xlsx";

    QXlsx::Document *xlsx = new QXlsx::Document(fn);

    unsigned int row = 1;
    unsigned int col = 1;

// запись заголовков таблицы
    for(QHash<QString, double>::const_iterator row_it = paramList[0].constBegin(); row_it != paramList[0].constEnd(); row_it++)
    {
        QString key  = row_it.key();
        xlsx->write(row , col++, (key + "_REAL"));
        xlsx->write(row , col++, key);
    }
// запись данных
    for(QVector<QHash<QString, double>>::const_iterator it = paramList.constBegin(); it != paramList.constEnd(); it++)
    {
        row += 1;
        col = 1;
        xlsx->write(row, col++, QString::number(static_cast<double>(row - 1) * 0.0625).replace('.' , ','));

        for(QHash<QString, double>::const_iterator row_it = it->constBegin(); row_it != it->constEnd(); row_it++)
        {
            QString key  = row_it.key();
            double val = row_it.value();
            double realValue = paramList_real[row - 1][key];

            xlsx->write(row, col++, QString::number(realValue).replace('.' , ','));
            xlsx->write(row, col++, QString::number(val).replace('.' , ','));
        }
    }

     xlsx->save(); 
}
```

Объем данных достаточно большой, приблизительно 201x1000. При записи в 288 строку 1 столбца приложение выводит ASSERT failure in QVector::operator[]: "index out of range" и закрывается.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Проверяйте индексы при вызове, чтобы они укладывались в диапазон текущего размера массива. Ошибка явно об этом говорит. Ну и ознакомьтесь с тем, что такое [mcve].

Comment: @älёxölüt , спасибо, проблема действительно была в индексе, а именно paramList_real[row - 1][key].